# Sort a list by presence of items in another list

Tags: python, list, sorting

Suppose I have two lists:

```
a = ['30', '10', '90', '1111', '17']
b = ['60', '1201', '30', '17', '900']
```

How would you sort this most efficiently, such that:

list `b` is sorted with respect to `a`. Unique elements in `b` should be placed at the end of the sorted list. Unique elements in `a` can be ignored.

example output:

```
c = ['30', '17', '60', '1201', '900']
```

Sorry, it's a simple question. My attempt is stuck at the point of taking the intersection.

```
intersection = sorted(set(a) & set(b), key = a.index)
```

Comment: so you only want to preserve those in ```a``` which are duplicated in ```b```, then add the rest of ```b``` to them?

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly, `sorted(b, key=(a+b).index)` should do it.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, but that's quadratic time because of doing `.index` on every element.

Comment: ```c = [i for i in a if i in b]+[i for i in b if i not in a]```   . Note that though you are not doing any sorting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to actually sort here. You want the elements in `a` which are in `b`, in the same order as they were in `a`; followed by the elements in `b` which are not in `a`, in the same order as they were in `b`.

We can just do this with two filters, using the sets for fast membership tests:

```py
>>> a = ['30', '10', '90', '1111', '17']
>>> b = ['60', '1201', '30', '17', '900']
>>> a_set = set(a)
>>> b_set = set(b)
>>> [*filter(lambda x: x in b_set, a), *filter(lambda x: x not in a_set, b)]
['30', '17', '60', '1201', '900']
```

Or if you prefer comprehensions:

```py
>>> [*(x for x in a if x in b_set), *(x for x in b if x not in a_set)]
['30', '17', '60', '1201', '900']
```

Both take linear time, which is better than sorting.

Comment: nice, not sure if it's better to `filter(b_set.__contains__, a)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Sure; that should be marginally faster.

Comment: Sorting booleans is practically linear time as well. I challenge you to find `a` and `b` where your solution is faster than mine, or to make mine look non-linear :-)

Comment: Nice one; I'll attempt your challenge at a later time but more out of curiosity than competition; I think your solution should be linear time even in the worst case.

Comment: I don't think mine is linear time. It just seems like it. I believe the number of comparisons is indeed O(n) but the data movements are O(n log n), but since the latter have a much lower hidden constant, they're not noticeable. That's what I mean with "practically linear".

Comment: @HeapOverflow It depends whether Timsort will continue to extend an existing run when it can; if so, it only has to produce two runs, then merging is linear time. I was under the impression it does this, but I defer to you if you say it doesn't.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean Timsort keeps two (or more?) runs and tries to append the next element to one of them? It doesn't do that. That could become kayasort :-). Timsort just finds existing runs, does binary insertion sort if they're too small (very likely with random data), and then merges them. I've added benchmarks to my answer now.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom dictionary, with the keys being the entries in `a` and the values their position. Then sort `b` according to the values in the dictionary. You can use `dict.get` for the lookup and `inf` if the value is not present:

```
a = ['30', '10', '90', '1111', '17']
b = ['60', '1201', '30', '17', '900']

d = {i:ix for ix, i in enumerate(a)}
#{'30': 0, '10': 1, '90': 2, '1111': 3, '17': 4}
sorted(b, key=lambda x: d.get(x, float('inf')))
#['30', '17', '60', '1201', '900']
```

Answer (score 2):

As you gave the hint of using `set`, it seems to me that the two lists contain non-duplicated items. Then you can simply do list comprehension:

```
c = [x for x in a if x in b] + [x for x in b if x not in a]
```

This is O(n^2), however. If your list is large and want to make it faster, try to build a set of `a` and `b` respectively and use them for membership check.

Comment: simple one, the first thing that came into my mind,

Comment: You make to linear time by doing this ` [x for x in a if x in set(b)] + [x for x in b if x not in set(a)]`

Comment: @Ch3steR That doesn't make it linear. That makes it slower quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

Your title is actually clearer than your description and can be pretty directly translated to code:

> Sort a list by presence of items in another list

Code:

```
>>> sorted(b, key=set(a).__contains__, reverse=True)
['30', '17', '60', '1201', '900']
```

or

```
>>> sorted(b, key=lambda x, s=set(a): x not in s)
['30', '17', '60', '1201', '900']
```

Sorting booleans is practically indistinguishable from linear time, and these solutions are faster than the accepted solution both on your example data as well as on example data I tried with millions of random numbers (where about half of `b`'s elements were in `a`).

**Benchmarks**

```
   n    b in a   kaya1    kaya2    heap1    heap2    heap3
----------------------------------------------------------
   1024 53.12%  0.00046  0.00033  0.00020  0.00067  0.00018
   2048 51.03%  0.00142  0.00069  0.00048  0.00071  0.00060
   4096 50.34%  0.00226  0.00232  0.00127  0.00183  0.00125
   8192 50.42%  0.00938  0.00843  0.00328  0.00471  0.00351
  16384 50.38%  0.02010  0.01647  0.00776  0.00992  0.00839
  32768 49.96%  0.03987  0.03165  0.01661  0.02326  0.01951
  65536 50.20%  0.08002  0.06548  0.03326  0.04828  0.03896
 131072 50.04%  0.16118  0.12863  0.06671  0.09642  0.07840
 262144 50.06%  0.32698  0.26757  0.13477  0.19342  0.15828
 524288 50.08%  0.66735  0.54627  0.27378  0.38365  0.32496
1048576 50.00%  1.34095  1.08972  0.54703  0.78028  0.65623
2097152 50.03%  2.68957  2.20556  1.13797  1.60649  1.33975
4194304 50.01%  5.36141  4.33496  2.25494  3.18520  2.70506
8388608 49.99% 10.72588  8.74114  4.56061  6.35421  5.36515
```

Note:

- `n` is the size of `b`.
- `a` is prepared as a `set` before benchmarking the functions, in order to focus on their differences. The size of `a` is always `8388608` in order to keep `in a` checks constant time (even `set`s get slower when they get larger).
- `b in a` is the percentage of elements of `b` in `a`. I made them so that this is about 50%.
- `kaya1` and `kaya2` are from the accepted answer by @kaya3, modified so that they do what I think is the task (sort `b` by presence of items in `a`, not "`a & b`" followed by "`b \ a`").
- `heap1` and `heap2` are my above two solutions using `sorted`.
- `heap3` is the fastest solution without `sorted` that I was able to write.
- The results are times in seconds.

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat
import random

def kaya1(a_set, b):
    return [*filter(lambda x: x in a_set, b), *filter(lambda x: x not in a_set, b)]

def kaya2(a_set, b):
    return [*(x for x in b if x in a_set), *(x for x in b if x not in a_set)]

def heap1(a_set, b):
    return sorted(b, key=a_set.__contains__, reverse=True)

def heap2(a_set, b):
    return sorted(b, key=lambda x: x not in a_set)

def heap3(a_set, b):
    not_in_a = []
    append = not_in_a.append
    in_a = [x for x in b if x in a_set or append(x)]
    in_a.extend(not_in_a)
    return in_a

print('   n    b in a   kaya1    kaya2    heap1    heap2    heap3')
print('----------------------------------------------------------')

A = random.sample(range(2**24), 2**23)
B = random.sample(range(2**24), 2**23)
a_set = set(A)

for e in range(10, 24):
    n = 2**e
    b = B[:n]
    print('%7d %5.2f%%' % (n, 100 * len(set(b) & a_set) / len(b)), end='')
    expect = None
    for sort in kaya1, kaya2, heap1, heap2, heap3:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: sort(a_set, b), number=1))
        print('%9.5f' % t, end='')
        output = sort(a_set, b)
        if expect is None:
            expect = output
        else:
            assert output == expect
    print()
```

Comment: It's occurred to me that there's a difference in behaviour between our two solutions; mine keeps the relative orders from list `a`, whereas yours keeps the relative orders from list `b`. The former matches the OP's attempted code, though it's not clear from the question text whether one or the other is intended.

Comment: @kaya3 Yeah, that's what I meant when I wrote about my modification of yours, and why I quoted the title and said that's clearest. Their example allows both interpretations, I tend to not trust people's code attempts, and if there are duplicates in `a` then `a.index` might just be bad. Maybe your interpretation is what the OP wants, maybe they're ok with either, but I think my interpretation is "nicer" or at least more likely what others are looking for if they search and find that title.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, and I'm not going to retract my upvote :-p

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should work.

```
intersection = sorted(set(a) & set(b), key=a.index)
intersection.extend([ele for ele in b if ele not in intersection])
```