# What is the fastest way to convert a dictionary frequency to list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, frequency

I have dictionary frequency as follows:

```
freq = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

It simply means that I have one `a`'s, two`b`'s, and three `c`'s.

I would like to convert it into a complete list:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

What is the fastest way (time-efficient) or most compact way (space-efficient) to do so?

Comment: Probably, why? .

Comment: There is a slim chance that it does. Python's sorting algorithm (Timsort) supposedly operates under the assumption that real world data sets are closer to sorted than random. Why not test it out?

Comment: have you considered list.sort() ? or even why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if the items are (or can be represented as) integers, and if the number of items between the smallest and largest item is sufficiently close to the difference between the two, in which case you can use [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), resulting in *O(n)* time complexity, where *n* is the difference between the smallest and the largest item. This would be more efficient than using other sorting algorithms, with an average time complexity of *O(n log n)*.

In the case of `List = [1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3]` as it is in your question, it is indeed more efficient to use bucket sort when it is known that `1` is the smallest item and `9` is the largest item, since only `8` is missing between the range. The following example uses `collections.Counter` to account for the possibility that there can be duplicates in the input list:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(List)
print(list(Counter({i: counts[i] for i in range(1, 10)}).elements()))
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Can you provide a list with items from 1 to 9 where that's faster than just using `sorted`?

Comment: As I stated in the answer, the OP's example of `[1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3]` is a good example of a list that is more efficient to sort with bucket sort than other sorting algorithms.

Comment: On that list, your solution is vastly *slower* than using `sorted` (over 20 times).

Comment: And that is only because `sorted` is a built-in function implemented in C.

Comment: I'd say that's not the only reason. Anyway, the question remains: Can you provide a list where yours is actually faster?

Comment: If you think that is not the only reason, I would love to hear that other reason you have. If you understood algorithms, you would not need any example of a list.

Comment: For that list, little overhead (no extra data structure and stuff). For larger lists, the fact that I think it's nearly linear. For two-valued lists especially (as I recently used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60235049/12671057)), but I think for few-valued lists it's still similar (looked into that a while back, don't fully remember the stats).

Comment: The fact is that bucket sort has an average time complexity of *O(n)* when the aforementioned conditions are met while other general sorting algorithms have an average time complexity of *O(n log n)*. With a sufficiently large `n`, bucket sort would always have better efficiency than other sorting algorithms despite overhead of implementation differences.

Comment: Because you are apparently unable to understand why *O(n)* is more efficient than *O(n log n)* and get stuck in implementation details. Feel free to re-implement Python's `sorted` function (using the algorithm of timsort) in pure Python and then compare the timing with my implementation of bucket sort.

Comment: Nah, I understand it's more efficient for sufficiently large n. I just don't live exclusively in the theory ivory tower but also visit the real world and run benchmarks :-). And I get the feeling that you underestimate how large n needs to be in this case. I tried it up to n = 16,000,000, where `sorted` was still faster. And I do suspect that `sorted` needs only O(n) comparisons here.

Comment: Nah, it rather shows that you didn't look into Timsort and this special case enough.

Comment: Speak for yourself. Timsort has an efficiency of *O(n)* only when the input is close to being pre-sorted, which the OP's list is not.

Comment: Says who? Where's the proof? Also, I didn't say Timsort has O(n) here. I said I suspect it needs O(n) **comparisons** here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this into two **O(N)** passes: one to catalog the numbers, and one to create the sorted list.  I updated the variable names; `List` is an especially bad choice, given the built-in type `list`.  I also added 10 to each value, so you can see how the low-end offset works.

```
coll = [11, 14, 15, 12, 16, 17, 19, 13]
last = 19
first = 11

offset = first
size = last-first+1

# Recognize all values in a dense "array"
need = [False] * size
for item in coll:
    need[item - offset] = True

# Iterate again in numerical order; for each True value, add that item to the new list
sorted_list = [idx + offset for idx, needed_flag in enumerate(need) if needed_flag] 
print(sorted_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most compact way I usually use is list comprehension -

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
freq = {i: 0 for i in lst}
for i in lst: freq[i] += 1
```

Space complexity - O(n) 
Time complexity - O(n)